# SQL 'WHERE' retrieve all data from a filter

Tags: sql, if-statement, where-clause, wildcard

With this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE name = 'Peter'
```

I can retrieve all data from Peter from `table1`. This can be done with the "Wildcard *".

**Question**

Is there any kind of wildcard for the `WHERE` part? For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE name = *
```

This option of course not working, but I am looking for a wild card there so that all names will be included in my query. I know it's easier to remove the `WHERE` statement, but due to some reasons I still need it.

Comment: one way to do this (without a wildcard though) ==> SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE name IS NOT NULL;

Comment: But i need to replace only "Peter" so i still have the "=" in my code. So this is not working because at the end i will have: = "IS NOT NULL".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE True OR name = 'Peter'
;
```

---

This may look silly, but it can come in handy when generating query strings, eg in PHP/PDO:

---

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM names
     WHERE ($ignore_name OR name = :the_name)
     AND ($ignore_address OR address LIKE :the_address)";
```

---

, where the `$ignore_xxx` variables are either `True` or `False`, and completely under your control (**not** user-input!)

Comment: While I've seen this strategy many times, its performance can degrade significantly. If performance is important Dynamic SQL is preferrable.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!

Comment: @TheImpaler in postgres, the invariant conditions are detected by the query generator when preparing the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from table1 
where name = 'Peter' or name = name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query output into your WHERE clause like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE [name] IN (SELECT DISTINCT [name]
                    FROM table1)
```